# Is it possible to autocomplete commands within quotation marks within InputField?

Tags: cdf-format, enterprise-cdf, auto-completion

I wrote the code to enter the command in quotation marks in InputFeed. Of course, there are methods such as InputField[#,String], but I must use the InputField[#, Boxes] format and quotation marks.

```
Manipulate[ToExpression@ToExpression@in,
Style[ Control@{{in, "\"\""}, InputField[#, Boxes] &, ImageSize -> {600, 50}}, 20]]
```

Now I was typing the command here, and I tried to enable autocomplete using CTRL+K.

[image]

The auto-completion feature works well when there is no quotation mark. However, CTRL+K does not run if there is a quotation mark.

Question 1. Can the auto-completion function be executed using CTRL+K even if there is a quotation mark?

Question 2. In Wolfram Player, there is no auto-completion function. I want to make the auto-completion function available in Wolfram Player as well. For example, save the command list as "command.txt" and import and apply it from the CDF file. Of course, normal CDF files do not support "Import". However, I can produce Enterprise CDF.

Comment: I don't understand why you are still insisting on inputing strings. Just use `ToExpression[in]` and keep `InputField[#, Boxes] &`.

Comment: It's the result of the project I'm working on so far. If you look at this, you'll understand what you're trying to do.
http://naver.me/FFSIHR4D

Comment: I will explain. Enterprise CDF supports string in Inputfield. However, there are two problems with InputField[#,String]. First, it cannot be expressed in StandardForm. Second, when entering a command, the last bracket cannot be closed. For example, after entering "N[Pi", the input of the last bracket "]" was blocked. When I re-express in the InputField[#, Boxes] and quotation marks, the two problems were solved.

Comment: @Domen did not suggest to use `Input[#, String]`, he suggested using `ToExpression[in]` instead of `ToExpression[ToExpression[in]]` and not including quotes in the input field. Did you try this? If so, what went wrong?

Comment: Domen's suggestion is quite right. I started to do that at first. But when I write it like Domen's method, I can't complete the input on the Wolfram player. I can produce an Enterprise CDF. So I can create a CDF that allows free input in the InputField with the Wolfram player. However, even if it is an Enterprise CDF, command input is not allowed. If I didn't write in quotation marks, I can only enter up to N[Pi... The last bracket ] is not input. That's why I used the InputField[#,Boxes] and quotation marks in it again. My previous description was not clear.

Comment: Look here. When you created Enterprise CDF including InputField, there is an issue that the Wolfram language input was limited.
  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95003/approximate-unitstep-for-use-in-enterprise-cdf?rq=1